# Route workflow automatically after interaction node in Maximo 7.6

Tags: maximo

Is there a way to automatically re-route a record into the workflow after interaction node in Maximo 7.6 ? I have invoked an OOB dialog which would send communication and once SEND button is clicked the record remains in workflow due to interaction node and user has to re-route it automatically . Is there any workaround for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your Action is CREATECOMM. I won't promise it will work, but you could try this:

1. Create an Action Group that has Actions of CREATECOMM and then ROUTEWF. (You might need to create Actions with these AppActions, first.)
2. Create a Sig Option with the name of the Action Group and with Advanced configuration to be used by the user in the UI.
3. Change your Interaction Node; put the name of the Sig Option you just made in the Action property.

Comment: We cannot create action ROUTEWF since there is no value ROUTEWF in Maximo 7.6

Comment: Pity. That means making such an Action yourself. Try doing that with an Autoscript with an Action Launch Point.